# CakePHP 3 - Combining reusable validators for repeated columns in tables?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

**Goal:** I have a database with a number of tables that share a lot of columns. For instance, both the `users` table and the `orders` table have a set of four columns that make up an address. Instead of repeating the same rules inside the `validationDefault()` functions of each table I would rather make the rules reusable.

**Attampt:** I looked at [Book: Creating Reusable Validators](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-reusable-validators) and [stackoverflow question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895489/cakephp-3-using-reusable-validators) and I understand this usage:

```
public function validationCustomAndDefault()
{
    $validator = new \App\Model\Validation\CustomModelValidator();

    return $this->validationDefault($validator);
}
```

**Problem:** basing a validation funtion a custom validation creates a new validation object. I want to combine multiple reusable validations. How can I realise this? So in sort of pseudo code:

```
// In src/Model/Table/UsersTable

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator1 = new \App\Model\Validation\CustomAddressValidator(); // Bunch of columns defined in there
    $validator2 = new \App\Model\Validation\CustomOtherValidator();

    $validator = validator1 + $validator2;

    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using static functions. The custom validator class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Validation;

use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Validation for the four address fields
 */
class AddressValidator extends Validator
{

    static public function addAddressFields(&$validator)
    {
        // Add validation rules to existing validator

        $validator
                ->scalar('address_city')
        // ...
    }
}
```

And usage in my `UsersTable.php`:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    // ...

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->nonNegativeInteger('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', 'create');

        // ...

        AddressValidator::addAddressFields($validator);
    }
}
```